# Trouble getting to apache server from public

Tags: linux, apache, networking, webserver, portforwarding

I am having trouble getting access to my Apache server from computers outside my network. I set up an Apache server. I forwarded the ports from my router to the local IP address of my server (the 192.168.X.X thing).

It works on localhost very well (on the server), and also on the WAN IP of my router (on the devices in my local network (ex: a phone)). I have done a lot of research and have been all day trying to figure it out. I run Debian-based Linux as the OS. My public IP address (the one I find on http://checkip.dyndns.org/) does not give me my Apache "It's working" page, instead it gives me a "The connection was reset" on Firefox.

The ports of my localhost, the WAN IP address of the router, as well as my public IP address show open 80 ports (on which I run the Apache server) on Nmap. I have also set up DMZ to my local ip address.

I am really confused and cannot seem to find a way to get through. Can anyone please help me with this?

Comment: If you really mean help, rather than down voting, comment and say what's wrong with the question. **don't be evil**

Answer (score -1):

Port Forward your public IP xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx to your local IP being something like 192.168.xx.xxx!  So that anyone trying to access your server from outside the network will have to ask public IP to route traffic to internal IP the 192.168.xx.xxx... Also make sure your firewall configuration allows this...

A port can only be used by one program at a time.

heres a how to even tho i dont usually like this site 
http://www.wikihow.com/Set-Up-Port-Forwarding-on-a-Router

Then all public requests will be handled by your local address which already works on your network  but it must be the public IP you get from whatismyip.com

Please try and up vote I've been banned for being unhelpful i assume!

Comment: Thank you for the reply, 
I understand what you say, but I cannot figure out which 000-default.conf file I need to modify and what directive I should use to add my local/public IP. Also, I do not see the reason to add the IP address to Apache configs, since I am port forwarding from the router. Thanks for helping. Really. Thanks.

Comment: 000-default.conf is the one i  edit... in etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf

Comment: do you have a static or dynamic public ip ? and you dont have a domain name?

Comment: I have set up static (local) IP for my laptop, and I don't have a domain name. I would like to test it with IP first then register a domain name.